# Finite State Machine for Synchronous Circuit

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines

Using the diagram below I have to fill out the state table for Q1+, Q0+, G, and F.

[image]

Assuming Q0+ and Q1+ are the inputs to the left and right flip-flops, respectively, fill out the following state table for the circuit above:

Q1: 0 0 1 1

Q0: 0 1 0 1

Q1+: 0 1 0 1

Q0+: 1 0 1 0

G: 0 0 1 1

F: 0 1 0 1

Based on the diagram and the values of Q1 and Q0, would my values be correct for Q1+, Q0+, G, and F?  Thank you!

Comment: Your diagram + text makes no sense to me.  For starters, I have no idea what the difference is between Q0 and Q0+.  And there is no difference between Q0 and F, and Q1 and G.  Further, your state machine does not have a defined reset/initialization state.

Comment: I think Q0+ is just the inverse of Q0, because of the placement of the inverter.  And yeah aren't Q0, F, and Q1+ all the same values?

Comment: Q0+ probably signifies the value of Q0 in the next state...

Comment: So than would Q0+ would be the same as G and Q1?

Comment: @CharlesWitiker, yes your last comment is right, but your table is incorrect and barely readable! I went through the full derivation in my answer for you. Don't forget to accept answers if they are correct. That helps future visitors find answers quickly, and I noticed you haven't done that for any of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming:**

- Q0 is the output of the DFF on the left,
- Q1 is the output of the DFF on the right,
- Q0+ = Q0* = Q0 next,
- Q1+ = Q1* = Q1 next

We can derive expressions for the values Q0*, Q1*, F and G from observations of the circuit.

- F = Q0 (connected to output of Q0 DFF)
- G = Q1 (connected to output of Q1 DFF)
- Q1* = Q0 (connected to output of Q0 DFF)
- Q0* = ~Q1 (connected to inverted output of Q1 DFF)

You may notice that all of the above equations only depend on the Q0 and Q1 state registers. This means this is a Moore FSM since the output depends only on the present state. We can build the entire truth table from just the Q0 and Q1 states on the left side:

**Truth Table**

```
Q1 Q0 | Q1* Q0* G F
-------------------
0  0  | 0   1   0 0
0  1  | 1   1   0 1
1  0  | 0   0   1 0
1  1  | 1   0   1 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  When you said assuming Q0 and Q1 are the DFF's on the left and right respectively, you meant Q0+ and Q1+ right?

Comment: I assume that Q0 and Q1 are the outputs of the left and right DFFs, and Q0+ and Q1+ are the inputs. I think my assumptions are the same that you listed in the question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  Thank you! I see that you flipped the values for Q0 and Q1, most likely because of how I didn't put them sequentially.  Does that mean, I should flip the values for Q0+ and Q1+?  Like make Q0+ 1100 and Q1+ 0101?

Comment: Ah, I think the ordering is arbitrary, either one is technically correct. But I think you're right, usually the convention is have the highest number on the left and the lowest number on the right (little-endian). I'll update it to standard notation

Comment: I really appreciate the help.  I actually think I made a mistake in my post, Q1+ should be 0101 and Q0+ should be 1100, right?

Comment: That's right, as shown in the updated table. But I must mention that it is very difficult for others to understand statements like "Q1+ should be 0101", because that ordering assumes a certain ordering of the truth table, and it isnt clear what "0101" means at all. From my original table order (which was correct but different) we would have had a disagreement about "0101". In the other table order it would have been "0011".

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I'm not sure of how to make tables and things on here without it getting sloppy, hah.  When creating a finite state machine diagram for this, how would I go about it without having any inputs?  I have created four bubbles with the states 00, 01, 10, and 11 with the output of F=0 F= 1 F=0 F=1, respectively.  How do I show Q1+,Q0+, and G however with no input?

Comment: The diagram will still have states (four bubbles) and transitions (four lines with arrows). If you had inputs, you would write the inputs/outputs on the transition lines. For Moore FSM, you just write the outputs on the transition lines since there is no inputs.

Comment: Sorry I was incorrect. The outputs get written inside or next to the bubbles. Your diagram is correct, but the G output should be written as the F output is. So there would be nothing written on the transition lines.

Comment: Ah, alright.  Are my transition lines correct?  00 to 01 to 11 to 10 back to 00?

Comment: Yes, those are correct.

Comment: Yes those are all correct. You can thank me by voting up and accepting my answer! :D